# change field from within function

Tags: java, swing, serialization

Okay, this should be my last question for now :)  Anyway, I have a String called mode and  ArrayLists called lines and components that get edited in my program by various functions.  Everything works great normally.  But when I load from a serialized save file, I stop being able to edit those values from within functions.  After loading, if I ever try to change the value of mode or add to one of those arraylists, the change happens within that function, but then it reverts back to it's old value when that function is over.  How can I change these fields globally from within functions after loading?

```
public class Main implements Serializable {

  ArrayList<Component> components = new ArrayList<Component>();
  ArrayList<Connection> lines = new ArrayList<Connection>();
  String mode = "";


  void makeErase() {
    mode = "erase";
    header.setText("Click something to erase it");
  }

  abstract class Component extends JLabel implements MouseListener,            
                                                     MouseMotionListener, 
                                                     Serializable {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { 

      if (mode.equals("erase")) {
        drawPanel.remove(this);
        components.remove(this);
        for (Input input : inputs) {                    
          for (Connection connection : input.connections) {
            System.out.println("hey");
            drawPanel.remove(connection);
            lines.remove(connection);
            connection.output.connections.remove(connection);
          }
        }
      }

      void save() throws IOException {
        String savepoint = "C:\\apcs\\hi.txt";
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(savepoint);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);

        for (Component c : components) {
          for (Output o : c.outputs) {
            for (Input i : o.inputsReceivingThis) {

            }
          }
         }
        ProjectState state = new ProjectState();
        out.writeObject(state);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();

      }

      void load() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        ProjectState state;
        String loadpoint = "C:\\apcs\\hi.txt";
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(loadpoint);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        state = (ProjectState) in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        drawPanel.removeAll();
        drawPanel.repaint();


        components.remove(components);
        lines.remove(lines);
        components=state.projectComponents;
        for (Component component : state.projectComponents) {
          component.addMouseListener(component);
          component.addMouseMotionListener(component);
          drawPanel.add(component);

          for (Output output : component.outputs) {
            for (Input input : output.inputsReceivingThis) {
              Connection c = new Connection(currentConnectionID, output, input);
              lines.add(c);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    class ProjectState implements Serializable {
      ArrayList<Component> projectComponents;
      ArrayList<Connection> projectLines;
      public ProjectState() {
        projectComponents = components;
        projectLines = lines;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem you are having is assuming the deserialised object is the same object as the original. This is not the case it is a different object with the same state.

Comment: Still, why would that affect the object's ability to change fields in the Main class? @BevynQ

Comment: I wonder if Java is thinking that you're loading a java.awt.Component and not an object of your own Component class. I would change the name of your Component class to something else that doesn't clash with pre-existing GUI class names. Just a guess and not tested.

Comment: Just an observation: your code formatting is pretty bad. Please strive to make your code as clean as possible with good consistent indentation, judicious use of white space, and good formatting when posting it here. It can be quite difficult trying to understand someone else's code, I don't think that's asking too much for you to put in the effort to not make this any more difficult than it needs to be, especially since you're asking us to put in effort to help you.

Comment: What I think is happening is that when you are in the method you are accessing the deserialised object and chainging it's properties so when you are in the method you see the changes, but when you leave the method, the object you were changing gets discarded and you are back to the original which was not changed.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a correctly indented SSCCE.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what's going on, since I explicitly set the ArrayLists in the non-serialized Main class to equal the ones from the serialized load file.  Also, the String "mode" is never serialized in the first place, and changing it doesn't work either...    

And I've changed the formatting to make it not awful - sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks @BevynQ - after testing some stuff, I'm pretty sure you're right.  However, I have absolutely no idea how to go about fixing the problem - will this require lots of rewriting?

Comment: post load have a look at your object structure in your debugger and make sure it looks like what you think it should look like. When you are in the function look at the object ID(the java one) that you are changing, and look at it when you leave the function, they should be identical.

Comment: Given that the save/load which is giving you problems, try to simplify your code a little bit. I don't think you need an Input and an Output, a single ConnectionEndpoint class should suffice. Once you have done that then try and add a save/load back in.